# How can I set vertical-align to all cells in a table by setting the table element's style?

Tags: css

I would like to have all cells in a  with "vertical-align:top" style. For technical reasons outside my control, I cannot define a new class, or change the stylesheet at all; nor can I set "style" for individual cells, or even rows. All I can do is set the "style" attribute of the `<table>` element itself.

Using `<table style="vertical-align:top">` fails -- apparently, it sets the alignment of the table within its own context, *not* of individual cells inside it. Is there any other alternative that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

You can use css

```
table tr td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: How to apply this to only one table out of many tables in the page?

Comment: @kten You can give a class to the table and write `table.class tr td`

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I can see there is no way to do this without some form of access to either the `td` itself or a style sheet.

Can you apply a workaround like this one? It's not pretty and invalid according to the W3C, but should nevertheless work in all browsers:

```
<style type='text/css'> table.topalign td { vertical-align: top } </style>
 <table class="topalign"> 
  ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the "classic" HTML valign attribute on the table. The value will be inherited by the cells.

```
<table valign="top">
  …
```

See [Tables, Table formatting by visual user agents, Horizontal and vertical alignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-valign) in the HTML 4 spec.

Answer (score -2):

table tr {valign: top}
In this case you don't need to use css class.